# Twitter Bootstrap 3 reduce number of columns in row on resize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

What is the best approach to reducing the number of columns in a row when viewing on different devices.

My page has 3 columns on desktop but I want to reduce to two on a tablet. What should happen to my third column ?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <!-- column one -->
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12>
  <div>Content One</div>
 </div>

 <!-- column two -->
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12>
  <div>Content Two</div>
 </div>

 <!-- column three -->
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-?? col-xs-12>
  <div>Content Three</div>
 </div>

 </div>
 </div>
```

Desktop

[image]

Tablet

[image]

For large, medium and xs layouts its fine but it breaks for sm. My layout should be 
6 3 3 for large and medium and
12 for xsmall

For small I want to reduce the 3 column (6-3-3) to 2 column (8-4) but how should I handle the third column

thanks

a

Answer (score 3):

You could wrap the 3rd column into the next row and make it full width..

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <!-- column one -->
 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
  <div>Content One</div>
 </div>

 <!-- column two -->
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
  <div>Content Two</div>
 </div>

 <!-- column three -->
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div>Content Three</div>
 </div>

 </div>
 </div>
```

Play with it on Bootply: http://bootply.com/99087

Also, don't forget to close the class attributes with double quotes.

**Option 2**..

Another option is to apply a special class to pull the 3rd column right on `small` devices:

```
/* pull-right on small devices */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .pull-right-sm {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

http://bootply.com/99089

**Option 3**..

Another options is to use nesting as demonstrated here: http://bootply.com/99100

Comment: thanks but the page will host content from a news feed so it should display Large Column Small Column for the whole page and not Large Column Small Column on one row and Large Column full width for alternate rows. Maybe I need Javascript Masonry style plugin ?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand exactly what you're trying to achieve, but I edited my answer with another option and [Bootply demo](http://bootply.com/99089).

Comment: thanks again..i've updated my question with a graphic to illustrate what i'm after

Comment: Take a look at: http://bootply.com/99103 -- Another variation of the  nesting example.

Answer (score 1):

#### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/aRuwIFiN/1/edit

[image: DESKTOP]
[image: TABLET]

You're going to have a left over column as three is an odd number.

```
<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-7">
 <div>Content One</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5">
 <div>Content Two</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-7">
 <div>Content Three</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-5">
 <div>Content One</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-7">
 <div>Content Two</div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5">
 <div>Content Three</div>
</div>  

 <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-7">
  <div>Content One</div>
 </div>

 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5">
  <div>Content Two</div>
 </div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-12">
 <div>Content Three</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```